# C++ ingresar valores hasta que haya un 0

Tags: c++

Realice un programa que lea 15 juegos de n valores, emita el mayor de cada juego y el promedio de todos los valores ingresados. Cada juego termina al leer un valor 0 (cero).

Mi duda consiste en como separar los juegos cada vez que lea un 0.

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
       int juego, mayor, sum=0, div=0;
       float  promedio=0;
    
       for (int i=0; i<=4; i++){
            cout << "Ingrese el valor del juego, para finalizar este juego ingrese 0"<< endl;
            cin >> juego;
            if (i == 0){
                mayor = juego;
                }
            if (juego > mayor) {
                mayor = juego;
                }
            sum+=juego;
            div++;
       }
        promedio = sum/div;
    
        cout << "El juego de mayor valor es: "<< mayor<< " y el promedio de los juegos es: " << promedio<< endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Si dice *n valores* porque el límite del `for` es `<= 4`?

Comment: lo hice para probar, porque no sabia bien lo del 0

Answer (score 0):

según he entendido lo que estas buscando es que finalice el programa una vez lea un 0 por teclado. Si es eso, una posible solución sería añadir una variable booleana que este inicializada a un valor, como por ejemplo true. Añades una condición al bucle de manera que siga el bucle mientras i<=4 y la variable booleana siga manteniendo su valor predeterminado, de esta manera una vez que cualquiera de las condiciones deje de cumplirse, se romperá el bucle y terminará la ejecución del programa. El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int juego, mayor, sum=0, div=0;
   float  promedio=0;
   bool flag=true;

   for (int i=0; i<=4 && flag; i++){
        cout << "Ingrese el valor del juego, para finalizar este juego ingrese 0"<< endl;
        cin >> juego;
        if (i == 0){
            mayor = juego;
            flag=false;
            }
        if (juego > mayor) {
            mayor = juego;
            }
        sum+=juego;
        div++;
   }
    promedio = sum/div;

    cout << "El juego de mayor valor es: "<< mayor<< " y el promedio de los juegos es: " << promedio<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo necesitas ingresar por teclado valores enteros para 15 juegos, pero cada juego puede tener 0 o más valores ingresados.
Entonces necesitas crear 2 `arreglos` que vayan guardando el `mayor` valor y el `promedio` de cada juego; tener en cuenta que el arreglo de `promedios` tiene que ser de tipo `float` porque al `sumar` los valores ingresados y dividir entre la `cantidad` de valores ingresados puede dar como resultado un decimal.
Te dejo el código de tu ejercicio comentado;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int juego, mayor, suma, contador,n=15;
   int arregloMayores[100];//Guardar el mayor valor de cada juego
   float arregloPromedio[100];//Guarda el promedio de los valores ingresados para cada juego

   for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        contador=0;
        suma=0;
        cout<<"\t JUEGO "<<i+1<<endl;
        do{
            cout << "Ingrese el valor del juego, para finalizar este juego ingrese 0"<< endl;
            cin >> juego;
            if(juego==0)break;//Parar el juego para i cuando se ingrese 0
            else{//si el valor ingresado es diferente que 0
                if(contador==0){//si es el primero elemento ingresado para el juego i
                    mayor=juego;
                }else{
                    if(mayor<juego)mayor=juego;                 
                }               
                contador++;
                suma=suma+juego;    
            }               
        }while(juego!=0);      
        arregloMayores[i]=mayor;
        arregloPromedio[i]=(float)suma/contador; 
   }
    
    //Mostramos el mayor valor y promedio cada juego
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"\t RESULTADOS DEL JUEGO "<<i+1<<endl;
        cout<<"Mayor valor: "<<arregloMayores[i]<<endl;
        printf("Promedio %f \n" ,arregloPromedio[i]);       
    } 

    return 0;
}
```